# How to do IF when creating JSON with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

It is great to create JSON objects with LINQ like:

```
JArray J1 =
   new JArray(
      new JObject(new JProperty("n1", "v1"))
      new JObject(new JProperty("n2", "v2"))
   )
```

You can even trow in an iterative element with select like:

```
JArray J1 =
   new JArray(
      from p in posts
      orderby p.Title
      select new JObject(new JProperty("title", p.Title))
   )
```

Or a choice with the ternary operator (a?b:c) :

```
JArray J1 =
   new JArray(
      q ?
      new JObject(new JProperty("n1", "v1"))
      :
      new JObject(new JProperty("n2", "v2"))
   )
```

But how to do a simple IF?

The ternary operator does not work without the "else" part.
This does not work as it gives an annoying "null" in the object:

```
JArray J1 =
   new JArray(
      q ?
      new JObject(new JProperty("n1", "v1"))
      :
      null
   )
```

If q is false, the result is:

```
[null]
```

instead of an empty array:

```
[]
```

My question is: how to conditionally add a new object in the above constructions?

Comment: Have you tried to use a where clause ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ. LINQ  is a query language and apart from that `from .. query`, all the rest is just object creationg through the JObject, JArray constructors.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos NewtonSoft.com calls this Creating JSON with LINQ, but you might be right. Perhaps this is not what Microsoft calls LINQ.

Comment: @Roland it's not what JSON.NET calls LINQ either. LINQ is LINQ, a very specific query language and classes. Json.NET's LINQ namespace contains the classes that allow you to use LINQ to query a parsed JSON object, or when you want to return JObject/JArray objects from a LINQ query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your example, you have to create an empty array depending on the condition (not an array containing null),

For your simple example at the end, I would move the conditional ternary outside of the expression

```
JArray J1 = q ?
   new JArray(
      new Object(new JProperty("n1", "v1"))
   )
   :
   new JArray()
```

For the Linq part, to process the collection of element, you can simply filter out by your condition using a `Where` clause, as per comments

```
  from p in posts
  orderby p.Title
  select new Object(new JProperty("title", p.Title))
  where q
```

Comment: Great, esp. the empty array. But how to use the Where without a Select? I need something like IF even if there is no iteration

Comment: @Roland what do you mean by no iteration ? No data ? Can you provide some precise example ?

Comment: Simple: if Q = True: the JArray has 1 element {n1, v1}, ELSE the JArray is empty. Thats it. No table "posts", no "from", "select". I only talked about the iteration to show how sophisticated Linq is, and why I wonder that there seems to be no IF.

Comment: in this way of writing linq (the "query" way), you need a `select`, but you can just use a neutral select : 

`from x in list
select x
where Q`

This will return the objects in list that satisfy Q condition only. It will return an empty `IEnumerable<T>` if no object satisfy the condition.

Comment: In my case there is a field for contactperson1 and one for contactperson2, but that one may be empty. Having to convert this input to an array is ugly, but in the end I need a Json array, so, then, converting the input to an array is not that ugly after all. So you solved my problem. Thanks for helping me think along new paths. Still a pity that there is no real simple IF here.

Comment: @Roland Ok, it smells like à [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Probably there is a better global way of tackling this issue, but for that we would need a better view of what you are trying to achieve from start. Glad to have been able to help, though.